# Does Github's API allow opening issues?

Tags: php, github

Is it possible to use php on your server to open an issue in Github? I'm trying to use Github's issues as a means to report errors, and let visitors report problems when they occur.

Answer (score 1):

It sure does, you can use their API, specifically to create an issue: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Here's the PHP wrapper: https://github.com/ornicar/php-github-api#open-a-new-issue